# Using UIImage to present a local image from a string containing the name

Tags: swift

```
 myCell.sourceIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@item.sourceIcon!];
```

any thoughts? I get an error saying to change the format of my imageNamed which is for sure correct I think.

More like this now per Axel's suggestion.

```
myCell.sourceIcon?.image = UIImage(named:item.sourceIcon!)
```

Where, by the way, item.sourceicon! = "bbc"

Also, the output error is EXC_I386_INVOP

Comment: UIImage constructor in Swift is `UIImage(named:"yourImageName")`

Comment: Thanks Axel :)
Your solution worked great. I ran it as 
`myCell.sourceIcon.image = UIImage(named:"imagename")`
But now i've now tried this:
`myCell.sourceIcon.image = UIImage(named:item.sourceIcon!)`

But the images do not appear to work now.

Comment: Please elaborate on "item.sourceIcon!". The constructor should be as simple as Axel has suggested. I feel you are not pointing to the image properly. Also unwrapping with a ! (bang) operator is not always a good idea. I'd suggest using an optional binding (if let {}) statement.

Comment: sourceIcon is an optional string containing the name of the image to be loaded in this format "image.png"